# Is it possible to get only the total number of black frames from a video clip using ffmpeg (windows user)?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a .avi video clip which runs for 30 minutes with 30 fps. I want to know the total number of black frames in that clip instead of showing every black frame. Is it possible to do it using ffmpeg?

Comment: You might need [FFmpeg blackDetect API](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blackdetect)

Comment: I tried ffmpeg -i sample.avi -vf "blackdetect=d=0.03:pix_th=0.00" -an -f null - 2>&1 2>result.txt

Comment: I need to plot either the number of black frames or the duration of black frames in the total length of the video file.